# MATLAB and clearing the swap space

Tags: matlab, memory-management, out-of-memory, ram

In the debugging mode I stop at some breakpoint and do some matrix manipulation in order to test the program. These manipulations are computationally expensive so MATLAB uses the swap space on my linux system. Then, after continuing the program running, the swap space is almost full so MATLAB crushes. Is there a way I could clean the swap at the debugging node? Doing `clear all` and `clear classes` makes effect only on RAM memory, but do not affect the swap.

Comment: Swap is managed at the Operating System level.  All MATLAB can do is make requests to the OS for memory.  Where that memory lives, whether physical RAM or swap, is out of MATLAB's hands.
You can use the "whos" and "feature memstats" commands to determine memory usage and what is using it, to some extent.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Swap isn't special, so just work through this as as a regular out-of-memory issue. If you free up memory, you'll indirectly free up the swap that's being used to back it (or avoid having to use swap to supplement it).

Swap space is just an OS-managed backing store for virtual memory. From a normal program's point of view, swap *is* RAM (just slow RAM) and you don't manage it separately. (Well... you can "wire" pages to prevent them from being swapped out and so on, or use OS APIs to directly manipulate swap, but those are low-level platform-specific details, (like, below `malloc`), and not exposed to you as a Matlab M-code programmer, and not what you want to do here.) If your Matlab program runs out of memory, that means it's used up or fragmented its process's virtual memory, not something in particular about your swap space. (Unless there's a low-level bug somewhere.)

When this happens, you may need to look elsewhere in your Matlab program (e.g. in global variables, figure handle properties, or other levels of the function call stack) to find additional data that hasn't been cleared yet, or just restart the Matlab process to fix memory fragmentation (which can happen if your code fills up the memory with lots of small arrays).

Like @siliconwafer suggests, `memory`, `whos`, and `feature memstats` are good tools for debugging this. And if you're stopped inside the debugger, realize you can't actually clear everything until you `dbquit` out of it.

Doing large matrix operations inside the debugger is not necessarily a recoverable operation: if you've modified arrays held in local variables in the stack frame(s) you're working on, but there are still copies of them held in other variables or frames, Matlab's copy-on-write mechanism needs to hold on to both copies of the arrays, and you might be out of luck for that run of the program if you hit your RAM limits.

If `clear all` and `clear classes` after exiting the debugger are not recovering enough memory for you, that smells like either memory fragmentation or a C-level memory leak (like in a MEX file). In either case, you need to restart Matlab to resolve it. Avoid the use of large `cellstr` arrays or other arrays-of-small-arrays to reduce fragmentation. And take a good hard look at your C code if you're using any custom MEX functions.

Or you just might not have enough memory to do the operations you're doing.